# How can I replace node-cron with a command line script in a node.js application

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, scheduled-tasks

I would like to change the implementation shown below to using a command line script in a node.js application. How do I do it?

```
var cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('* * * * *', () => {
  getBananas();
});
```

Comment: Do you mean bash or something similar? You can run node via the command line.

Comment: Yes @Phix. Could you help with what that would look like exactly?